# How do you reverse Allow from {IP}?

Tags: apache-2.2

I've been tasked with adding Trac to an existing Apache instance. In trying to set up authentication, I've discovered that we allow folks coming from our internal IP to bypass authentication. I need to undo that within the /trac location. Given the below config fragment, how can I do that?

```
  <Directory /var/www/tools.example.com/public_html>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    AuthUserFile /var/www/users.auth
    AuthGroupFile /var/www/groups.auth
    AuthName "Please log in"
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user
    Allow from {some-ip}
    Satisfy Any
  </Directory>

  …

  # For trac
  WSGIScriptAlias /trac /var/www/tools.example.com/public_html/trac/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi
  <Location "/trac/login">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Please log in to trac"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/trac.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
  </Location>
```

Is there some way I can unset the "Allow from all" just within /trac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "Satisfy Any" in the general rule, add a `Satisfy All` in your /trac so that it requires both conditions.

Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#satisfy